# Run two nested for loops in parallel to create matrix

Tags: python, multithreading, numpy

I've written a method that takes in an integer "n" and creates a square matrix where the values of each element are dictated by their respective i,j indices.

When I build a small matrix 30x30 it works just fine, but when I try to do something larger like 1000x1000 it takes very long. Is there any way that I can speed it up with multiprocessing?

```
def createMatrix(n):
    matrix = []
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        row = []
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            value = 1/(i+j-1)
            row.append(value)
        matrix.append(row)
    return np.array(matrix)
```

Comment: Using mgrid - `i,j = np.mgrid[1:5,1:5]; 1/(i+j-1)`. Using ogrid - `i,j = np.ogrid[1:5,1:5]]; 1/(i+j-1)`.

Comment: Did the performance matter (the question goal!??) and did you really need **parallel** that you mentioned in your title???? I have proposed a parallel one that was extremely fast (the fastest among the proposed answers). numba library is compatible with numpy and will be faster in many cases.

Comment: Performance certainly matters since my approach was taking extremely long and that was the main reason for the question. I did like Marat's answer since it brought the time to a more than acceptable time, is quite elegant, and answered first. Thanks for your answer too, very interesting library, I had never heard of it!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parallelizing two computation-bound `for` loops in Python is not trivial because of GIL. The good news is that your case is perfectly vectorizeable:

```
def createMatrix(n):
    return 1 / (np.arange(n)[None, :] + np.arange(n)[:, None] + 1)
```

Explanation:

- essentially, your formula for the matrix is `X[row][column] = 1/(row+column-1)`, where rows and columns are 1-based
- `np.arange(n)` creates a range that can be used for rows or columns
- `[None, :]` and `[:, None]` turn it into a 2d array, `1 x n` or `n x 1`
- `numpy` then broadcasts dimensions, replicating row and column indexes to match dimensions - thus, implicitly tiling both into `n x n` when added
- since both ranges are 0-based, using `+1` instead of `-1`

As a rule of thumb, it is almost never a good idea to use for loops on numpy arrays. A vectorized approach (i.e. matrix form computations) is orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: as a comment I would use `1/ (np.arange(1,n)[None,:]+np.arange(1,n)[:,None]-1)` to keep OP's formulation. But result it's the same

Answer (score 4):

It's not a good idea to use fors to fill a list then convert it to a matrix. the operation that you have can be vectorized with numpy from scratch. if you think that given the `i,j`,  `M(i,j) = 1/(j+i-1)` considering that both indices starts at 1.

Here's my proposal :

```
def createMatrix2(n):
    arr =np.arange(1,n+1)
    xx,yy = np.meshgrid(arr,arr)
    matrix = 1/(xx+yy-1)
    return matrix
```

looking at Marat answer, I think his/her it's better, so tested the 3 methods:

**EDIT**: added wwii method as createMatrix4 (correcting the errors):

```
import numpy as np
from time import time

def createMatrix1(n):
    matrix = []
    for j in range(1,n+1):
        row = []
        for i in range(1,n+1):
            value = 1/(i+j-1)
            row.append(value)
        matrix.append(row)
    return np.array(matrix)

def createMatrix2(n):
    arr =np.arange(1,n+1)
    xx,yy = np.meshgrid(arr,arr)
    matrix = 1/(xx+yy-1)
    return matrix

def createMatrix3(n):
    """Marat's proposed matrix"""
    return 1 / (1 + np.arange(n)[None, :] + np.arange(n)[:, None])

def createMatrix4(n):
    """ wwii method"""
    i,j = np.ogrid[1:n,1:n]
    return 1/(i+j-1)
#test all the three methods
n = 10000

t1 = time()
m1 = createMatrix1(n)
t2 = time()
m2 = createMatrix2(n)
t3 = time()
m3 = createMatrix3(n)
t4 = time()
m4 = createMatrix4(n)
t5 = time()
print(np.allclose(m1,m2))
print(np.allclose(m1,m3))
print(np.allclose(m1,m4))
print("Matrix 1 (OP): ",t2-t1)
print("Matrix 2: (mine)",t3-t2)
print("Matrix 3: (Marat)",t4-t3)
print("Matrix 4: (wwii)",t5-t4)
# the output is:
#True
#True
#True
#Matrix 1 (OP):  18.4886577129364
#Matrix 2: (mine) 1.005324363708496
#Matrix 3: (Marat) 0.43033909797668457
#Matrix 4: (wwii) 0.5138359069824219
```

So Marat's solution is faster. As general comments:

- Try to avoid fors loops
- Think your problem as operation with indices and dessing operations with numpy arrays directly.

For last, given Marat's answer I thought my proposal is a easier to read, and understand. But it's just a subjective view

Comment: How does this compare: `i,j = np.ogrid[1:n+1,1:n+1]]; 1/(i+j-1)`

Comment: @wwii *insert I don't know. you tell me meme here* you could try and propose an edit to this answer or just create youts

Comment: ogrid performance should be similar to @Marats answer, I was curious and when making timing comparisons they should be done on the same machine. - On repl.it using timeit the ogrid and Marat's solution are comparable.

Comment: i've added. performance is similar slower but in the order, i also increased n by 1 magnitude order

Comment: now give me my upvote (?)

Comment: @wwii, look at the `ogrid` output.  It's essentially `(np.arange(n)[:,None], np.arange(m))`.  `ogrid` looks nice and clever, but has a lot more setup overhead.  `np.meshgrid` with 'sparse=True`' also works.  Also `np.ix_`.

Comment: ? I think Marat's solution is better. You were providing the timing info for general elucidation not votes weren't you?

Comment: @hpaulj - yep I saw that, that's why I was curious about the timing.

Comment: of course, just kiding, but I think that you could take the code, and add your proposal and run all to get all times in your machine... whatever, hope it helps. as @hpaulj says, usually methods like ogrid has a function working in background, and are designed to mask this function with other notation in this case something matlab-like notation of array creation (`a:b`) wich is not native of python

Answer (score 2):

Your code can be written in another style, accelerated by numba library in a **parallel** no python mode:

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit("float64[:, ::1](int64)", parallel=True, fastmath=True)
def createMatrix(n):
    matrix = np.empty((n, n))        # np.zeros is slower than np.empty
    for j in nb.prange(1, n + 1):
        for i in range(1, n + 1):
            matrix[j - 1, i - 1] = 1 / (i + j - 1)
    return matrix
```

This solution will be faster than [the **Marat** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72619104/13394817) above 3 times.

**Benchmarks:** ([temporary link to colab](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1zzEm6gMc-3u6aDil2YsFLcD0_ZwqCyTt?usp=sharing))

---

```
n = 1000
1000 loops, best of 5: 3.52 ms per loop   # Marat
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.5  ms per loop   # numba accelerated with np.zeros
1000 loops, best of 5: 1.05 ms per loop   # numba accelerated with np.empty

n = 3000
1000 loops, best of 5: 39.5 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 19.3 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 8.91 ms per loop

n = 5000
1000 loops, best of 5: 109  ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 53.5 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 24.8 ms per loop
```